# How to format a proof by induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am reading a book where the following proposition is proved by induction:

If $n$ is a natural number such that $n>1$, then $n-1$ is a natural number.

Now, since the usual way of proving a statement of the form $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \; \; P(n)$ is to show that $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid P(n) \} = \mathbb{N} $, a possible approach would be to show that

$\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{If} \; n>1, \; \text{then} \; n-1 \in \mathbb{N}   \} = \mathbb{N} $ by induction.

However, the textbook instead shows that

$\{ n-1 \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \;\text{and} \; n>1 \} = \mathbb{N} $

My questions is : Why is this last statement equivalent to the first proposition?

Comment: FWIW: I very much prefer your approach!

Comment: Since I do not know how you are even defining the concept of $n-1$ in a way doesn't have "$n-1$ is a natural number" built-in, I cannot guess what your book is doing. But $\{ n-1 \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \;\text{and} \; n>1 \} = \mathbb{N}$ is effectively the converse of the statement you are trying to prove. Therefore proving it does not by itself prove that proposition. However, you may be misinterpreting the book's approach. Look carefully - they may be proving something more than you think.